# retriving user information - getting junk characters appended in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

When i am tring to retrive user information from mysql database, i am getting some junk characters appended to the column values and some column values are not displayed - but the data is available in database.

Here is code which is used to retrive user info:

```
user_controller.rb
edit_user = User.find( params[:id])
@realname = edit_user.realname - value is displayed properly
@username = edit_user.username - value is displayed properly
@email = edit_user.email - value is displayed by junk characters - but value is not displayed in rails console and value can be seen in mysql database.
```

i.e. email value obtained is 0/, job_desc is 0/
Phone values as 1111/
addresses values as Office/

```
@phones = edit_user.phones
   @phones.each do |phone|
    if phone.phone_type == "Office"
        @phone1 = phone.number
    elsif phone.phone_type == "Mobile"
        @phone2 = phone.number
    elsif phone.phone_type == "Home"
        @phone3 = phone.number
    end
   end

user.rb - model:
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :phones
    has_many :addresses
end
phone.rb
class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
end
address.rb
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
end
```

Can anyone guide me where i am making mistake or suggest me an approach to get user information properly without junk characters?

Thank u
Sudhir

Comment: A character encoding problem, perhaps?

Comment: i am not encoding anything - we are just saving and retriving the records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there must be something going on outside the code you supplied.

In rails console can you do the following...

```
u = User.new
u.realname = "1"
u.username = "2"
u.email = "test@something.com"
u.save

x = u.id

u = User.find(x)
puts x.email
```

And post the results of this

Comment: Here are the results:
irb(main):006:0> u = User.new
=> #<User id: nil, username: nil, realname: nil, email: nil, job_desc: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):007:0> u.realname = "1"
=> "1"
irb(main):008:0> u.username = "2"
=> "2"
irb(main):009:0> u.email = "a@c.com"
=> "a@c.com"
irb(main):010:0> u.save
=> true
irb(main):011:0> x = u.id
=> 49
irb(main):012:0> u = User.find(x)
=> #<User id: 49, username: "2", realname: "1", email: #<BigDecimal:1fac5b0,'0.0',4(8)>, job_desc: nil, created_at: 2011, updated_at: #<BigDecimal:1fa5338,'0.2011E4',4(8)>>
irb(main):013:0>

Comment: Hi,  I think I see the issue, one or more of your mysql columns is of the type DECIMAL which is why I think your code output is saying 'BigDecimal:1fac5b0,'0.0',4(8)' as the result of email.  Have a good look at your table structure and make sure that strings are VARCHAR and dates are DATETIME.  Let me know how you get on.  Worst case, remove the table and make a new one.